# How to zoom in to the center of a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to create a zoom in effect on my large div. I have searched many questions and still don't know how this work.

I want to be able to zoom into the center of the user screen instead of the set position.

http://jsfiddle.net/kB27M/1/

I have tried `css3 zoom` feature and `animate` `zoom` property but still can't pull this one. Can anyone help me about it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you want the div to stay the same size and just show part of the original div at a larger scale?

Comment: I need to have the large scale of the image but still be able to scroll to see the entire image.

Answer (score 2):

You should **scale** the div:

```
    .scaled {
       -moz-transform: scale(3);
       -webkit-transform: scale(3);
       -ms-transform: scale(3);
           transform: scale(3);
    }
    div {
        transition: all 500ms ease-in;
    }
```

Simply apply the CSS class to the div and then use the `transitionEnd`event to apply further styles via `.animate()`.

On `transitionEnd` (discard `live()`, use `on()`): [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rGECn/2/)

Comment: add transform-origin to control zoom coordonates effect